# React Native - How to access variable between two buttons

Tags: react-native

Trying to learn react native here and want to reuse a variable between two "buttons" to perform tasks.

Take for example a simple workflow:

- When the user presses *Start* a random number is generated and a
  message is displayed
- When the user presses *Check* I do some checking and display a
  message according to the results.

This is my approach:

```
  state = {
    statusText: "Press Start to begin",
    randNum: 0,
  };

  generateRandNum = () => {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    return rand;
  };

  pressStart = () => {
    this.setState({
      randNum: this.generateRandNum(),
      statusText: "started; " + randNum, //display randnum for simple check-debug
    });
  };

  pressCheck = () => {
    this.setState({
      statusText: "checked; ",
    });
  };
```

Above, when *pressStart* is pressed, returns an error saying `randNum` is not found.

This, however, does work, but now can't access the variable elsewhere

```
 pressStart = () => {
    this.setState({
      statusText: "started; " + this.generateRandNum(), //display randnum for simple check-debug
    });
  };
```

How can I properly update `randNum` to the generated number so that I can access it globally?

==== While the answer below works this is what I ended up using, which seems to work just the same.

```
 pressCheck = () => {
    this.setState({
      statusText: "checked; " + this.state.randNum,
    });
  };
```

Comment: I did try to set state of `randNum` inside `generateRanNum` function and doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize randNum anywhere, so in order to use it in both places, you should give it a value before the setState.

Try this :

```
pressStart = () => {
    const randNum = this.generateRandNum()
    this.setState({
      randNum: randNum,
      statusText: "started; " + randNum, //display randnum for simple check-debug
    });
};

pressCheck = () => {
    this.setState(oldState => ({
        ...oldState,
        statusText: "checked; " + oldState.randNum,
    }));
};
```

Comment: yes, I can get it to work for the first button `pressStart`, but then the randNum is not available for the second button `pressCheck`, which is still an issue with your suggested solution

Comment: I edited the post, you can get the oldState by passing it as argument and them do whatever you want with the old state :), hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thank you, though as it turns out I don't have to pass oldState, updated my original for reference.